# more, less are behaving like cat

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware

While installing a new RHEL on KVM host I am displaying a text file using `more` command. Problem is `more` is behaving like `cat` in virt-manager i.e. not displaying page-by-page and directly scrolling to the end of the page. I tried using `less` instead of `more` but it is displaying the same behavior.

Can anyone suggest what could be the reason for this?

**Edit** Based on comments I tried changing TERM to xterm during first boot. But that didn't have any effect. I tried this command `export TERM=xterm`

I got the env variables printed. I am pasting it hoping this might be a clue.[image: TERM-linux, PATH=xx,PWD=/,SHLVL=4,TEXTDOMAIN=vaos_init]

**Edit** I couldn't get it working. I noticed that before the script is executed, some other script is running and this might be setting some environment variable because of which `more` isn't working. I am now calling more command before this script start executing. And now it is working.

Comment: What is your `TERM` environment variable?

Comment: $TERM prints Linux. Should it be something else to get 'more' working?

Comment: What exact command are you using to display the file? Seeing that you are able to use vi your terminal must be working properly.

Comment: I am using simply `more foo.txt`. I have tried several other option with more and less. but nothing seemed to do paging of foo.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After help from a senior dev, I found out what was happening behind the scenes.

Suppose A.sh is executing `more` command like below:

```
more pathtofile
```

A.sh is being called by some other script like below:

```
pathtoA.sh | tee
```

Because of this `tee` command, `more` command in child script was not behaving as it should have been.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your environment is not correct. Specifically your `$TERM` environment variable may not be set. See [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/more.1.html) for the `more` manual entry.

> The more command respects the following environment variables, if
>          they exist:
>
> ```
>    MORE   This variable may be set with favored options to more.
>
>    SHELL  Current shell in use (normally set by the shell at login
>           time).
>
>    TERM   The terminal type used by more to get the terminal
>           characteristics necessary to manipulate the screen.
>
>    VISUAL The editor the user prefers.  Invoked when command key v is
>           pressed.
>
>    EDITOR The editor of choice when VISUAL is not specified.
> ```

Comment: $TERM prints Linux. Should it be something else to get 'more' working?

Comment: It depends on your termcap etc. I suspect. I'm not an expert. But perhaps try setting it to 'xterm' or 'vt100' ?

Comment: Setting to xterm didn't change anything. I tried getting printenv output during installation. Here is output : 

TERM=linux

PATH=**something**

PWD=/

SHLVL=4

TEXTDOMAIN=vaos_init

thats it.